# Como somar o resultado de count de tabelas diferentes no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Como somar o resultado de *count* de tabelas diferentes no SQL Server?

Exemplo:

Tabela *OBRAS* possui 755614 Registros

```
SELECT count(*) from OBRAS;
```

Tabela *TITULOS* possui 85106 Registros

```
SELECT count(*) from TITULOS;
```

Tabela *AUTORES* possui 19029 Registros

```
SELECT count(*) from AUTORES;
```

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4):

Não tem porque complicar, se quer somar várias coisas é uma operação aritmética simples.

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) from OBRAS) + (SELECT count(*) from TITULOS) + (SELECT count(*) from AUTORES);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/SumCounts.sql)

Seria interessante outra solução se a lista de tabelas fosse muito grande, mas essencialmente envolveria código que generalizasse isto ou uso de tabelas auxiliares.

Answer (score 3):

Caso você não esteja tão preocupado com performance, pode utilizar a consulta abaixo:

```
select sum(total) from
(SELECT count(*) as total from OBRAS
union all
SELECT count(*) as total from TITULOS
union all
SELECT count(*) as total from AUTORES) as totalConsultas
```

Comment: Eu sugeria substituir o UNION pelo UNION ALL. Caso duas tabelas tenham o mesmo numero de registos vai contar apenas metade.

Comment: boa, alterando a resposta ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pergunta simples mas, ao mesmo tempo, curiosa. Há algumas soluções. Por exemplo, além das soluções propostas por rLinhares e Maniero, eis outra:

```
-- código #1
with 
C1 as (SELECT count(*) as Q from OBRAS),
C2 as (SELECT count(*) as Q from TITULOS),
C3 as (SELECT count(*) as Q from AUTORES)
SELECT C1.Q + C2.Q + C3.Q
  from C1 cross join C2 cross join C3;
```

Analisei os planos de execução das 3 soluções propostas e percebi que 2 soluções geram planos de execução semelhantes (talvez idênticos) enquanto que a terceira gera plano de execução diferente.

Comment: Exatamente o que você descreveu, surgiu essa necessidade de verificar a quantidade de registros, algo realmente simples mas interessante.